# SQLite :How can i add primary key to table using alter?

Tags: sqlite

Im trying to alter my table "Materiel" for make a primary key.,but this instruction is not working.

```
ALTER TABLE "MATERIEL" ADD CONSTRAINT "MATERIEL_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("MATRICULE")
```

This is stack trace:

> [00:22:39] Error while executing SQL query on database 'Data': near
>   "CONSTRAINT": syntax error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That won't work as that syntax is not supported by SQLite3 (see https://sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html). To do this, you need to re-create the table to include the constraint.